# Error downloading an object from Amazon S3 bucket using C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have used the very basic code for downloading a file from Amazon S3.
I have tried with two different codes.

1. The one which is commented `GetObjectResponse` throwing error

   ```
   System.Xml.XmlException: There are multiple root elements. Line 2, position 2.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 pos, String res)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   ```

   and etc.,
2. The code with the `TransferUtilityDownloadRequest`. Am not sure whether this method is correct or not. Found similar kind of example in [Amazon Site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-migration-guide-v2.html) so tried.

**Source Code**

```
  private static void AmazonS3Access()
    {
        string accessKey = "my_access_key";
        string secretKey = "my_secret_key";

        AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
        config.ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com";

        AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(
                accessKey,
                secretKey,
                config);
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
        request.BucketName = "bucket";
        request.Key = "myfile.extension";
        try
        {
            TransferUtilityDownloadRequest myfile = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest();                
            myfile.WithBucketName(request.BucketName);
            myfile.WithKey(request.Key);
            myfile.WithFilePath("D:\\S3File\\myfile.extension");  
            //GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request);
            //response.WriteResponseStreamToFile("D:\\S3File\\myfile.extension");
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

How to download the object from Amazon S3. Thanks in advance.

Note:

1. Am using VS 2010 with .NetFramework 3.5
2. Am using AmazonSDK.dll old version

**Solution:**

After adding the Network Proxy Credentials in the Program, it starts working fine.

Answer (score 0):

public Stream DownloadS3Object(string awsBucketName, string keyName)

```
    {
        using (var client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client())
        {
            Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
            GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest { BucketName = awsBucketName, Key = keyName };
            using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
            {
                response.ResponseStream.CopyTo(imageStream);
            }
            imageStream.Position = 0;
            // Clean up temporary file.
            // System.IO.File.Delete(dest);
            return imageStream;
        }
    }
```

pass the value in function get stream path save it in folder with use of below.

SaveStreamToFile(foldername + "/", MainStreamAwsPath);

and than you can apply simple c# code to download that folder.

Also Download latest AWS SDK for .net from aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet and add that dll in the project

Comment: It is not getting the `GetObjectResponse` value properly.. `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in AWSSDK.dll

Additional information: The 'link' start tag on line 5 position 2 does not match the end tag of 'head'. Line 6, position 3.` Error Message

Comment: Download latest sdk from http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/ .and add dll in the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Stream DownloadS3Object(string awsBucketName, string keyName)

    {
        using (var client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client())
        {
            Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
            GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest { BucketName = awsBucketName, Key = keyName };
            using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
            {
                response.ResponseStream.CopyTo(imageStream);
            }
            imageStream.Position = 0;
            // Clean up temporary file.
            // System.IO.File.Delete(dest);
            return imageStream;
        }
    }
```

Note:

Am using VS 2010 with .NetFramework 3.5
Am using AmazonSDK.dll old version