# Unzip AWS object

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am working on a project where I need to get Zip files from S3 Bucket.
I was able to copy these files one at a time to my EC2 instance using

```
  foreach (S3Object o in response.S3Objects)
        {

            GetObjectRequest requests = new GetObjectRequest();
            requests.BucketName = "mybucket";
            requests.Key = o.Key;
            GetObjectResponse responses = client.GetObject(requests);


            responses.WriteResponseStreamToFile(@"D:\myfile.zip");
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", o.Key, o.Size, o.LastModified);
        }
```

but I would like to unzip these files on the fly to a specific location instead of copy them locally. 
I tried the following but it did not work

```
 using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(responses.ResponseStream.ToString())) //unzip file 
            {
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {

                       archive.ExtractToDirectory(myPath);

                    }
                }

            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ZipFile.OpenRead()` takes a file name of a local file so that won't work. You can, however, unzip an archive in a `MemoryStream` (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767078/1428388) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20681442/1428388)).

Comment: I think that will not unzip the file to a local folder on my EC2 instance, correct? it reads the ZIP without unzipping it. I want to unzip the file to local folder on my EC2 instance.